# virtualenv macosX --no-site-package ignored

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I'm having problems with macOSX and virtualenv. It seems to ignore --no-site-package.
Using exactly the same commands with linux (archlinux) it works. It it macOSX 10.5 with python 2.5

```
curl -o virtualenv.py 'http://bitbucket.org/ianb/virtualenv/raw/tip/virtualenv.py
```

Create a new environment

```
python virtualenv.py --no-site-packages foo
New python executable in foo/bin/python
Installing setuptools...........................done.
```

Activate it

```
source foo/bin/activate
```

Try to install something in it. Despite virtualenv it looks for the system-wide install

```
easy_install cherrypy
Searching for cherrypy
Best match: CherryPy 3.1.2
Adding CherryPy 3.1.2 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages
Processing dependencies for cherrypy
Finished processing dependencies for cherrypy
```

Yet it doesn't find the module

```
(foo)guidage-multimodal:~ tristram$ python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  6 2009, 19:02:12) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cherrypy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cherrypy
```

I tried PIP after looking at [virtualenv --no-site-packages and pip still finding global packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages)
However it fails installing psycopg2 (some problems with gcc). Also I would like to be able to have a setup.py (from distribute) that does the whole woork

**update** On macOS 10.6 it works as it is supposed to work. Maybe is python 2.5 to old, or the install is broken, so I give up and will require macOS 10.6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also could be that the easy_install version was too old.
I'd suggest using pip:

```
easy_install pip
pip install virtualenv -U
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip -E env install cherrypy
```