# How to reset virtualenv and pip?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, ubuntu-10.04, pip

I installed virtualenv on my Ubuntu 10.04 server.

Now when I do pip freeze it shows me the following packages:

```
Django==1.2.4
distribute==0.6.10
python-apt==0.7.94.2ubuntu6.2
virtualenv==1.5.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

When I do "pip uninstall Django" it says:

```
pip uninstall Django
Uninstalling Django:
Proceed (y/n)? y
Successfully uninstalled Django
```

Ideally this should uninstall Django but it doesn't. I can still see the same packages when I do "pip freeze".

Now bear with me, the other weird thing is that when I create a virtualenv and then do "pip freeze" inside it, I see only one package and that is "wsgiref" which is weird because it should ideally be blank.

Also, in spite of creating this virtualenv with --no-site-packages I can still create a new django project with "django-admin.py startproject".

When I start python interpreter inside this virtualenv and do "import django" it gives me the error "No module named django".

Also when I try to install "pip install Django" inside the virtualenv it asks for sudo permissions which shouldn't happen ideally.

How do I sort out this mess. Any way to just reset everything pep and virtualenv?

Comment: You probably installed django with apt? (if so it should be in dist-packages)

You can run django-admin.py because it's in the PATH.

Comment: No it's not. When I do "dpkg -l" I don't see django anywhere. Also when I try to "sudo apt-get remove django" it says "Couldn't find package django. Same for python-django.

Comment: @Sushi Does the interpreter, started from outside a virtualenv, still gives an error when trying `import django`?

Comment: I don't get any error when I try "import error" from outside virtualenv. Also when I try django.VERSION it shows "(1, 2, 4, 'final', 0)".

Comment: @Sushi if `import django` works outside a virtualenv, do `import django;django.__path__`. This will show the path where django is still installed.

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke: I get this now ['/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django']

Comment: @Sushi That most certainly means you still have Django installed with your distribution, like ionelmc assumed before, even though dpkg and apt-get disagree.

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke: Yeah django is very much there. The trouble is it has spread to virtualenv as well where it shouldn't go. I am just removing the global django now to keep it sane. Thanks for your help all along.

Comment: For future, `toggle-site-packages` will turn off stuff that's not explicitly in your virtualenv, so if a package is installed globally, you can disable it/enable it using this command.

Comment: @Sushi, Accept the answer which worked for you.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell, the *only* purpose of a venv is to manage dependencies.

You should be safe to just `deactivate` the venv, delete it, and create a new one using `virtualenv venv; source venv/bin/activate`.

This will give you a fresh start.

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, but it got bumped to the front page, so it's hard to discern which versions of pip and virtualenv you are using.

There are a few things we can do to straighten this, nonetheless.

1. Exit all virtualenvs, and check your `$PYTHONPATH`. Make sure it's empty; else run `unset PYTHONPATH`.
2. Create a fresh virtualenv at `myenv` using `virtualenv --no-site-packages myenv`.
3. Activate `myenv` and check your `$PYTHONPATH` again. It should only have `myenv`.
4. Run `pip` with an absolute path, like so `myenv/bin/pip freeze`.
5. If `pip` is not available inside your virtualenv, you may have to install it manually.

Related: [virtualenv --no-site-packages and pip still finding global packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages)

Finally, start a python shell using `myenv/bin/python`, then run:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

If `pip` can find `wsgiref`, then `wsgiref` must be in one of the paths in `sys.path`. Use that clue!

Answer (score 2):

You can just delete your .venv file to remove all dependencies and then run `python3 -m venv .venv` for a fresh virtual environment.