# Heroku setup - pip fails to find/install dependencies

Tags: heroku, dependencies, installation, pip

I am trying to put a Django project on heroku following the instructions listed here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

However, whenever I get to this line pip fails :
`git push heroku master`

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Python/Django app detected
-----> Preparing virtualenv version 1.7
   New python executable in ./bin/python
   Installing     distribute...........................................................................................................................................................................................done.
   Installing pip...............done.
-----> Activating virtualenv
-----> Installing dependencies using pip version 1.0.2
   Downloading/unpacking Brlapi==0.5.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
     Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Brlapi==0.5.5 (from -r     requirements.txt (line 1))
   No distributions at all found for Brlapi==0.5.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
.       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python/django app

To git@heroku.com:fierce-stone-5846.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:fierce-stone-5846.git
```

The problem seems to be that pip can't find the dependencies. I have searched everywhere for an answer so any advice you can offer would be useful. If need be you can find the project along with the requirements.txt file here: https://github.com/Ballaw/Twithub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages) you can do:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
```

The --no-site-packages option prevents the virtual environment from having access to all the packages on your system.

Comment: That was the answer but it there is another problem. I think it has to do with the PYTHONPATH. Whenever I try to run the app on heroku the logs are as follows: