# pip vs. pip3 to deploy a Django app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I am trying to re-deploy a django app on Heroku after upgrading python from 2.7 to 3.4. When I (re)-run locallly

```
$pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Brlapi==0.6.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

However, when I push the app on Heroku I get

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.4.3
remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
remote:        Collecting Brlapi==0.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement  Brlapi==0.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for Brlapi==0.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Note that I have specified in a runtime.txt file the version of python (3.4.3). I suspect that the issue comes from the fact that Heroku is running pip instead of pip3. Could you tell me if this is the issue and if so, how do I get Heroku to run pip3 and if not, give me some hints on where I should investigate? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku setup - pip fails to find/install dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346838/heroku-setup-pip-fails-to-find-install-dependencies)

Comment: Where does the `Brlapi==0.6.1` requirement come from? It doesn't seem to be on PyPI, so `pip` can't find a suitable package to install.