# Heroku can't find pip (very strange)

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I push to master, this happened:

```
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 186 bytes, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Python app detected
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.3)
-----> Installing Distribute (0.6.35)
-----> Installing Pip (1.3.1)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
/tmp/buildpack_12iaablbmqzbb/bin/compile: line 164: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:xxxxxxxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

To be clear, I specified build pack, because heroku wrongly detected my python app as ruby app due to the existence of Gemfile.

This is the config I pulled from `heroku config`

```
BUILDPACK_URL: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
```

But this fail to compile my app, how can I really solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819482/i-am-trying-to-deploy-my-first-django-app-on-heroku-and-getting-error-a-pre-rece/43879758#43879758

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pip cannot find the dependencies. You can do is,

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
```

[virtualenv --no-site-packages and pip still finding global packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages)

Comment: Please read the error message thoroughly, app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory

Comment: have you tried the `pip freeze`, to see the list of installed app?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure they are not related pip. Because without specify the buildpack, it works.