# I am trying to deploy my first django app on heroku and getting error a pre-receive hook declined

Tags: django, git, heroku, buildpack, django-deployment

I have unsettling the buildpacks but it didn't work and I do have requirements.txt and procfile as well as virtual env.

```
 (deploy) C:\Users\Samar\Desktop\deploy\blog>git push heroku master
 Counting objects: 127, done.
 Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
 Compressing objects: 100% (122/122), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (127/127), 45.25 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
 Total 127 (delta 47), reused 0 (delta 0)
 remote: Compressing source files... done.
 remote: Building source:
 remote:
 remote: -----> Python app detected
 remote: -----> Installing Python 3.6.0
 remote: -----> Installing pip
 remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip remote:/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/bin/steps/pip-install: line 5: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory
 remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 remote:
 remote:  !     Push failed
 remote: Verifying deploy...
 remote:
 remote: !       Push rejected to trueblog.
 remote:To https://git.heroku.com/trueblog.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/trueblog.git'
```

Answer (score 2):

Heroku [only supports specifying a small set of python versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#supported-python-runtimes) in `runtime.txt`.  They currently only support 2.7.13 or 3.6.1.  If you specify any other runtime version, you get this wholly unhelpful error.

Change your `runtime.txt` to use one of the supported versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using python 3.5.1 but when I upgraded to python 3.6.1 everything worked.

Create a `runtime.txt` file and add `python-3.6.1` into it and place it into your base directory which is where you have your manage.py file. That should resolve your problem.