# Default libraries in freshly created Python virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I created a new virtual environment using the python `virtualenv` tool.

```
virtualenv venv
```

I then activated the virtual environment

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then I did a `pip freeze` and this is what I got:

```
(venv)$ pip freeze
Flask==0.10.1
Werkzeug==0.9.6
itsdangerous==0.24
lxml==3.4.0
numpy==1.9.1
pdir==0.2.2
virtualenv==1.11.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I am wondering how so many libraries got installed when I did not even install anything in the virtual environment explicitly.

**UPDATE 1**: When some of the answers suggested, I used `virtualenv --no-site-packages` as well in Step 1, to create a fresh venv and the same problem persisted. As if using the argument had no effect at all.

**UPDATE 2**: I was able to solve the problem and have posted my experience below. As pointed in the comments; here is a related question; [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages), that helped me solve the problem.

Comment: I am using homebrew-ed python on Mac OS X 10.10. Earlier I was using Python on Ubuntu and never faced the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages

Comment: ^ Thanks. This was useful.

Answer (score 4):

Those are the libraries that are already installed globally on your system.

Best practice is to use the [`--no-site-packages`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/1.6.4/#the-no-site-packages-option) option when creating the virtualenv in order to avoid this exact issue.

Comment: For some reason I thought --no-site-packages had become the default in virtualenv

Comment: I am still facing the problem even after using --no-site-packages. I was using python on ubuntu earlier and never faced this problem. Fresh venv did not contain system libraries even when I did not use --no-site-packages. It was the default I suppose. Now even if I use --no-site-packages, nothing happens. (Using python on OS X 10.10)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem. In my ~/.bash_profile file; I had the following line which was creating a problem:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

As Martin Lewis, pointed out in an answer to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages), `--no-site-packages` will remove the standard site-packages directory from sys.path. But anything else that lives in the standard Python path will still remain.

P.S: I am still not sure why virtualenv works this way. Why include the packages that are there on PYTHONPATH. But at least knowing this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation - The --system-site-packages Option](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#the-system-site-packages-option):

> If you build with `virtualenv --system-site-packages ENV`, your virtual
>   environment *will inherit packages from
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages* (or wherever your global
>   site-packages directory is).
>
> This can be used if you have control over the global site-packages
>   directory, and you want to depend on the packages there. If you want
>   isolation from the global system, do not use this flag.

These libraries are already installed in your system. Unless you specify `--no-site-packages`, they'll be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

A 'hackish' solution will be to activate virtual environment and run

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

This will uninstall all those unwanted packages.