# How to setup Virtual Environment for Django development without internet?

Tags: django, python-venv, virtual-environment

Every time I create a Virtual Environment for Django, from inside the virtual environment, I need to run

```
pip install django
```

which requires internet access. 
Can I somehow install django globally on my machine and *"pull"* it from inside the Virtual Environment?
I am running Zorion OS(Ubuntu-ish).

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline). In particular the answers from Carl Meyer and chaokunyang look useful.

Comment: If you want django in *every* virtual environment, I think you could install it globally outside of virtual environment. Not sure if you want it by default, or not have to pip install it each time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101695/default-libraries-in-freshly-created-python-virtual-environment for sort of the opposite problem