# How to start virtualenv with clean dependency

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Is there a way to start a virtualenv with zero package dependency? Whenever I create a new virtualenv, I get a whole list of pip dependencies from global environment. I would like to start a project in a clean state and install dependencies as needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages

Comment: unless you use [system site packages](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#the-system-site-packages-option) it wont add other global dependencies

Answer (score 2):

In the latest versions virtualenv ensures that the project is started with a clean slate.

For older versions. Use this command

```
virtualenv [name] --no-site-packages
```

`--no-site-packages` flag will ensure that the project is started with a clean slate.

This flag is now deprecated.