# Install django-rest-swagger in virtualenv

Tags: django-rest-framework, virtualenv

I have two Django installations:

- Django 1.4 in the base *physical* python env,
- Django 1.7 in a virtualenv.

When I try to install django-rest-swagger working on virtualenv through:

```
pip install django-rest-swagger
```

It uninstalls Django 1.4 in my base *physical* python env, upgrading it to the last version.

How can I install django-rest-swagger in my virtualenv without modifications of Django version in my *physical* env?

Comment: Did you get into the virtualenv first with `source bin/activate`? You can also use the virtualenv's pip directly from `/yourvenv/bin/pip`.

Comment: I entered `workon myvirtualenvname` before pip ([virtualenvwrapper](http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/)), as I usually do for installing on virtualenv but, in that case, It did not work.

Comment: Try using the `--no-site-packages` option when creating the virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper. Also check answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages

Comment: I read, but my virtualenv is already using `--no-site-packages` option

Comment: Check your `PYTHONPATH` variable after activating the venv. You might have something in your `.bashrc` or other shell profile files injecting the system path before the virtualenv one.

Comment: @dukebody I'm sorry it was my fault: I'm doing it as sudo. Without sudo, it works fine.