# Virtualenv, no-site-packages, sys.path

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, pythonpath, sys

My essential problem is that I can't get `--no-site-packages` to "work."

I have read a bunch of posts on SO, including [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages). I'm a huge Ubuntu noob, and not much better when it comes to how python interacts with the os.

Other posts suggested that `printenv` would display PYTHONPATH When I am in my virtualenv, `printenv` doesn't appear to list "PYTHONPATH", but it's quite possible that what I should be looking for is a particular `dir` that I'm not aware of instead of the uppercase letters.

What I have noticed, however, is that when I run the python shell within the virtualenv, all of my global packages are listed.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with `virtualenv`, `.bashrc`, `Ubuntu` or `my brain`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If there's some kind, knowledgeable soul out there who is willing to help me out in a sort of back-and-forth process, I'd be very grateful. I haven't listed any of my output because, honestly, aside from the above, I'm not entirely sure where to start.

**Edit in response to comments; UTC: 07:41 19 Nov 2015**

Starting the environment:

```
notanambiturner@computer:~/Dropbox/$$ P/...$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Entering the environment:

```
notanambiturner@computer:~/Dropbox/$$ P/...$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)notanambiturner@computer:~/Dropbox/$$ P/...$
```

System Packages:

```
(venv)notanambiturner@computer:~/Dropbox/$$ P/...$ pip freeze
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
apt-xapian-index==0.46
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bleach==1.4.2
blinker==1.3
cffi==1.1.2
characteristic==14.3.0
chardet==2.3.0
colorama==0.3.3
command-not-found==0.3
....
virtualenv==13.1.2
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.7.1
wheel==0.26.0
whitenoise==1.0.6
xdiagnose==3.8.1
zope.interface==4.1.2
(venv)notanambiturner@computer:~/Dropbox/$$ P/...$
```

`sys.path`:

```
(venv)notanambiturner@computer:~/Dropbox/$$ P/...$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['',
'/usr/lib/python2.7', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',     
'/home/notanambiturner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',   
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
>>>
```

You can clearly see that site-packages is included in `sys.path` which is super annoying.

Python3 seems slightly better, not that I know how to use `pip freeze` with it (or even if I can):

```
(venv)notanambiturner@computer:~/Dropbox/$$ P/...$ python3
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>>
```

**Next edit. My [mind is bottled](https://youtu.be/0DFBoLZC3Bw?t=8s) further. UTC 08:00 19 Nov 2015**

Because I'm a conspiracy theorist, I tried creating a venv outside of Dropbox.

```
notanambiturner@computer:~$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)notanambiturner@computer:~$ pip freeze
wheel==0.24.0
(venv)notanambiturner@computer:~$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['',
 '/home/notanambiturner/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/notanambiturner/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/notanambiturner/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/notanambiturner/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/notanambiturner/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/notanambiturner/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/notanambiturner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
    >>>
```

What... the... heck... ? I mean, I suppose that's some sort of progress? Maybe there's something to do with my filenames (\$\$\ P/) that is causing issues? From what I've read, as long as I `sudo rm -rf venv` it should make no difference that I have created and deleted `virtualenv`s in the same directory previously. Is that right?

Argh.

Comment: Can you please enter the environments, run python and run `import sys; print(sys.path)` inside python; then add all the inputs and outputs you did/received to your post by editing it?

Comment: It is mostly related how to you activate for your virtualenv. Please post full commands and their output how you run them.

Comment: Thanks folks! I can't tell you how good it feels to have someone helping me with this super annoying problem. I have edited the post per your comments. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KlausD. updated! :)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa updated! :}

Comment: Looks like a bug in path quoting. If you can replicate it outside Dropbox, you might report that. You can delete virtual environments safely.

Comment: @KlausD. I'm not sure I understood your last comment. You're thinking it's just a bug in virtualenv?

Comment: If you didn't know,   "--no-site-packages DEPRECATED. Retained only for backward compatibility. Not having access to global site-packages is now the **default behavior**."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a bug when using $ in the path name (at least on Ubuntu).