# Why is my virtualenv's pip listing packages in my lib/python2.7 directory?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

In my home, I have a directory named `lib/python2.7` (there are actually five directories like that, for different python versions). Since this is a shared hosting ([Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com)), that directory is fundamental to me. There, I have stuff like `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` installed, since as customer of a shared hosting, I have no access to `sudo` and installing global packages.

However, when I create a virtualenv:

```
$ mkvirtualenv myenvironment
$ workon myenvironment
$ which pip
# outputs the myenvironment's path to pip
$ pip freeze
```

The command shows the whole packages list under my `lib/python2.7` (this includes the same virtualenv packages, and conflicting packages I have due to... legacy... reasons). This also annoys me if I want to install a package which is the name of a package in `lib/python2.7` since it does not allow me to update it.

Right inside the `workon` environment, I try to check whether the PYTHONPATH has weird stuff, but it is empty:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
# shows a blank line
```

It is also empty if I try that command out of any virtual environment.

It seems that `--no-site-packages` is default but solves just part of the problem. This means: `pip freeze | wc -l` displays a lesser value when in an environment than when executing globally, out of any environment, which tells me that there are certain already-provided packages that are being excluded and are from the hosting itself (and not installed by me since, again, the hosting is *shared* and I don't have access to global space).

My question is: How can I solve this? I want my virtualenv not list the packages in `$HOME/lib/python2.7`

*Please avoid dupe-linking to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages), nothing was useful there and still does not have an accepted answer. I wrote this question after reading and trying each solution in that question*

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to specify python version. You can specify python version with which you want to create virtual environment using command like

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 virt/virtname --no-site-packages
```

Because when you not specify a python version, virtualenv creates a environment with pythonv2.7 and hence all packages end up in the folder you mentioned.

Comment: This worked for me, but the format of the -p flag was different: `virtualenv --python=python3.6 --no-site-packages venv`. The default is the interpreter that virtualenv was installed with.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution after deeply digging. **This is a Webfaction custom** but this could apply to any installation like this if the problem occurs.

The core of the problem is that **Webfaction configured a sitecustomize.py file for us**. The file is located at `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/sitecustomize.py` and adds by itself the contents of `~/lib/pythonX.Y` (and conditionally the contents of any python app under `~/webapps` if you are working under a directory of it to run a python script).

Even when the virtualenv's python executable is a different one, it will load the said `sitecustomize.py` file each time it runs as the base python executable does.

The workaround here? Create an empty sitecustomize.py in your virtualenv to override the other:

```
touch ~/.virtualenvs/yourvenv/lib/pythonX.Y/sitecustomize.py
```

And it will work. [Take this as reference if you are stuck here like I was](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/4253/simple-virtualenv-usage-with-django)

**Notes**: Replace X.Y on each case with the corresponding version you are working. Additionally remember: *You cannot remove or edit the base sitecustomize.py since you are in a shared hosting, in this case. However, overriding will work for each case as long as you do this for every virtualenv you want.*