# virtualenv setup with --no-site-packages accesses global packages

Tags: python, linux, pip, virtualenv

I've setup the virtual env (linux) using:

```
python virtualenv/virtualenv.py rootpy_env --no-site-packages
```

but after activating it I can still "see" the global packages.

I can't just upset the PYTHONPATH as suggested in some old [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages) because it will break other packages that are global and that I need. 
Executing `pip install --upgrade setuptools` install the new package in the site/package folder of the python in virtualenv, but seems like when executing python scripts the global package is picked up even though I run the script using ./rootpy_env/bin/python - which is a virtualenv one.

Is there a way to force python first to "look" into the local site_packeges?

Adding the path to the beginning of PYTHONPATH variable didn't help.