# How to prevent setup.py from using system packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py

I'm using a `setup.py` script to install a python package into a virtual environment. However some of the dependencies of this package are being found in a folder `/opt/common/CentOS_6-dev/python/python-2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and I would like instead for these to be reinstalled into my virtual environment location (`~/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages)`.

My $PATH does not have the `/opt/common` path listed in it, and my $PYTHONPATH only has one path, `/home/johnsoni/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages` listed.

I'm not sure why these system packages are being imported and used when trying to install with `python setup.py`

```
Using /opt/common/CentOS_6-dev/python/python-2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Searching for PyYAML==3.12
Best match: PyYAML 3.12
PyYAML 3.12 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /opt/common/CentOS_6-dev/python/python-2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Searching for idna==2.6
Best match: idna 2.6
Removing idna 2.5 from easy-install.pth file
Adding idna 2.6 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/johnsoni/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Searching for chardet==3.0.4
Best match: chardet 3.0.4
Adding chardet 3.0.4 to easy-install.pth file
Installing chardetect script to /home/johnsoni/virtualenv/bin
```

Comment: old question, you probably figured out a solution. Did you create your virtualenv with `--no-site-packages`? Did you enable your virtualenv with `source bin/activate`?

Comment: recently I haven't been having this problem, and I believe the solution was to unset the `PYTHONPATH` variable that was referencing the system site packages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382925/virtualenv-no-site-packages-and-pip-still-finding-global-packages